# Is Byte implemented as Int anyway?

Tags: java, int, byte

I had a java game book recommend implementing all data as Int when possible, that that type runs the fastest. It said the Byte, Char, and Boolean are implemented as Int anyway, so you don't save space and the casting you end up having to do in the code because of the Byte data will slow it down. For instance, a cast is needed for

a = (byte)(b+c);

since the addition result is an Int, even when a,b, and c are all declared as Bytes.

I currently have a huge 2D array declared as Byte for my game, to save space and for bitwise operations. Is it actually saving space? I've also seen bitwise operations done on Ints in examples, do bitwise operations work as expected on Ints?

Comment: What book is that? Sounds like a *terrible* one

Comment: Could you name ("and shame") the book?  I'm interested to see what other little gems it has like this.  My guess is that it's a garbled piece of understanding... that on the stack or when laying out the data structure of classes; the JVM **may** choose to pad byte variables out to 4 bytes.  This is a common optimisation even under C.  But you can never say for certain that the compiler / JVM will ever do this.  The optimisation exists because a 1 byte read on *some* architectures is a 4 byte read and then a mask / bitshift.

Comment: Actually it was a "For Dummies" book, which are usually pretty reliable. One of the "part of 10s" ten tips for more efficient code.

Comment: @michael When was the book published? Or what version of Java does it cover?

Comment: @couling Actually, padding variables of type `byte` is mandated by the JLS in the case of individual variables (not so for arrays). Check out my answer for the link.

Comment: 1998, now out of print.

Comment: @michael I would strongly advise against following that book if it was published in '98; it's simply out of date. A *lot* has changed since Java 1.2. Heck, Java *8* will be out in a few months.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is generally incorrect. In fact, this is outlined in the [JVM Specification §2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3):

> The primitive data types supported by the Java Virtual Machine are the numeric types, the `boolean` type ([§2.3.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4)), and the `returnAddress` type ([§2.3.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.3)).
>
> The numeric types consist of the integral types ([§2.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.1)) and the floating-point types ([§2.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.2)).
>
> The integral types are:
>
> - `byte`, whose values are 8-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero
> - `short`, whose values are 16-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero
> - `int`, whose values are 32-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero
> - `long`, whose values are 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, and whose default value is zero
> - `char`, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing Unicode code points in the Basic Multilingual Plane, encoded with UTF-16, and whose default value is the null code point (`'\u0000'`)

Now, for `boolean` it's slightly a different story. From [§2.3.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4):

> Although the Java Virtual Machine defines a `boolean` type, it only provides very limited support for it. There are no Java Virtual Machine instructions solely dedicated to operations on `boolean` values. Instead, expressions in the Java programming language that operate on boolean values are compiled to use values of the Java Virtual Machine `int` data type.

You can see differences in the bytecode depending on whether you use a `byte[]` or an `int[]`, so they're not identical:

```
byte[] b = {42};
```

```
ICONST_1
NEWARRAY T_BYTE
DUP
ICONST_0
BIPUSH 42
BASTORE
ASTORE 1
```

vs

```
int[] b = {42};
```

```
ICONST_1
NEWARRAY T_INT
DUP
ICONST_0
BIPUSH 42
IASTORE
ASTORE 1
```

---

> *Is it actually saving space?*

Yes, it likely is, especially if the array is very large.

> *do bitwise operations work as expected on Ints?*

Yes, they do.

Comment: Links to the spec are great. Does it say anywhere about `a cast is needed for a = (byte)(b+c);`?

Comment: @SpellingD That would be covered in the language specification, not the JVM spec. But it seems like the OP already knows that.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that `byte + byte = int`, requiring a cast, but `byte`s are implemented with 8 bits of data in memory, while `int`s are 32 bits. Therefore, using `byte`s will decrease the amount of memory that an array takes up by 4 times.

For example, if you had a 10 by 10 array of `byte`s, its size would be 800, but a 10 by 10 array of `int`s' size would be 3200.

[More information on this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on whether you are working with a single variable of type `byte` or with a byte array, `byte[]`. A byte array does indeed save space, with each Java byte using just a byte of memory (plus a constant amount of housekeeping data for the array object). However, a single local variable of type `byte` is actually stored as an `int` on the stack and takes the corresponding 4 bytes of memory. This is even expressed in the bytecode - there is the opcode `baload` - "Load byte or boolean from array" but there is no opcode for loading a byte from local variable like there is `iload` for ints. Similarily, local `char` and `boolean` variables actually are stored on the stack as an int and `int`-based opcodes are used to access them.

The entry [2.6.1 in JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1) also says that all local variables take either one or two "slots" on the stack, so the single-slot types byte, char, float and int all take the same space. The JVM cannot address a unit smaller than a single such slot, so in the case of a byte, 3 bytes are so to say wasted.

To wrap it up: do use `byte` **arrays** to save space, but in the case of **individual variables**, using a `byte` instead of `int` won't save space and may even have a small negative performance impact (it may however be required if you need `byte` for the semantics, e.g. counter wrapping behavior and such).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you perform a byte addition the return value is always an integer, reason being that 8bit + 8bit addition can always result in a value which is greater than 8bit.

e.g.

### decimal | binary

```
255 |   1111 1111
121 |   0111 1001
```

---

```
376 | 1 0111 1000
```

So if you try to store it in a byte again will definitely result in loss of data.
Instead of 376 you would get "120" if typecasting to byte is done.

You can definitely use int instead of byte and also the bit wise operations work perfectly on int.
refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm

Comment: technically the bit shift operators wont work correctly but the others will ;)

Comment: Cool... thanks for specifying that, personally I never came across using the bit shift operators. I will make note of it too..:)  Just curious to know what's issue with bit shift operators (just in case you wanna share)